# Appcelerator [ERROR] : SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length on win.open()

Tags: android, appcelerator-mobile

I have this simple example code:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Tab 1',
    backgroundColor:'#fff'
});

var mainView = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    width:'100%',
    height: '100%',
});

var webView = Ti.UI.createWebView(
{
    top:40, 
    width: 320,
    height: 200, 
    showScrollbars: false,
    cacheMode: Ti.UI.Android.WEBVIEW_LOAD_NO_CACHE
});
mainView.add(webView);

win.add(mainView);
win.open();
```

The problem is when runs `win.open()` command, I got the error

> Appcelerator [ERROR] : SpannableStringBuilder:
>   SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length on win.open()

Someone can help?